# Including Boost Python libraries produces C2039 compiler error

Tags: python, c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-python

I have built Boost_1.76 with the following configurations.

```
Compiler: MSVC 143
Build Tools: bootstrap.bat, b2 engine
Python Version: 3.7
b2 Command: b2 --build-dir=build/x64 address-model=64 threading=multi --build-type=complete --stagedir=./stage/x64 -j 12
```

```
// Conversion.hpp

#include <boost/python.hpp>        // import produces C2039
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>  // import produces C2039
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

```
// Conversion.cpp

#include "Conversion.hpp" // importing the header file produces the compiler error
```

I am compiling the project with the following specs.

```
Compiler: MSVC cl.exe
C++ Standard: ISO C++17
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
```

The compilation generates the following error.

```
C2039: '_copysign' is not a member of 'std' 
File: boost_1_76_python37\boost\core\cmath.hpp
```

I looked at `python.hpp` and `numpy.hpp` and could only find a reference to `std::cmath` inside `boost\python\detail\wrap_python.py`, which is used over `boost::core::cmath`. I checked the `std::cmath` header and `copysign` is neither declared nor defined. How do I make sure that my Boost library uses `copysign` in `boost::core::cmath`?

Comment: It looks as if there might be a preprocessor definition involved or incorrect compiler detection.

Comment: Which preprocessor definition are you referring to? As for the compiler, Boost1.76 by default does not support MSVC143. I have to modify bootstrap.bat, boost/config/auto_link.hpp and boost/tools/build to add MSVC143 support. The instructions are taken from this link https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues/735.

Comment: Ah. You might have to do another workaround, like e.g. a forwarding template like for GCC https://github.com/boostorg/core/blob/boost-1.76.0/include/boost/core/cmath.hpp#L155 You can also ask for help at the github issues or cppslack.